# Resynchronize Audio to Video

Tags: vegas-pro

When I have audio and video tracks de-synchronized, is there a way to make them synchronous?

A workflow:

- Add a video+audio track to a project;
- Crop a small *Event* in the middle and remove the rest;
- Uncheck `Ignore event grouping` option;
- Drag one of the tracks sideways;
  **Note** the audio track gets reddish background to indicate it is not synced to Video.
- Resize Video and/or Audio *Events* so that original start/end timestamps get lost;

Now I need to get Audio synced back to Video.
Obviously, dragging Video or Audio will not work as I have resized both *Events* individually.

How to get Audio back in sync, probably by losing cropping?
*I'm aware about opening the Event in the Trimmer and re-dragging the Audio track from there.*

Comment: I use [Sync Audio to Video](http://vegasaur.com/one-click-commands#SyncAV) command from Vegasaur toolkit. Note that this third-party extension is not free.

Comment: @altarvic Thanks for a suggestion. Please consider turning your comment into an answer so that others can upvote it; just make sure you notice that Vegasaur is a separate commercial product.

Comment: can Vegas set markers? If so set an audio marker and video marker before the desynching

Comment: @KvdLingen Thanks, but it will not work. Markers are tied to project's timeline, not to individual Events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does it for me (see the screenshots):

1. Set the cursor to the beginning of the audio event.
2. Drag the beginning of the audio event with the mouse to the beginning of the original clip (note: the cursor is still positioned at the cropped beginning) (screenshot 2)
3. Cut the audio event at cursor position (press S)
4. Repeat step 1 to 3 with the video event (screenshot 3)
5. Now you can easily synchronize video and audio by aligning the events (screenshot 4)
6. Delete the beginnings. (screenshot 5)[image: synchronizing audio and video]